# how to let a sub-class of UIViewController to be singleton

Tags: ios, design-patterns, uiviewcontroller

I have a lot of view controllers to interact with each other, so I am thinking to use "Mediator pattern" to manage this interaction. But in my opinion, it's better that all the controllers and coordinator should be singleton in "mediator pattern". it's easy to make coordinator to be singleton, but how to let a view controller to be singleton, anyone show some example here?

Comment: I won't lecture you on why it's not a good idea to make a view controller a singleton, but I will ask where you're having trouble. When you implement a standard singleton pattern, where does it not work for you? Post some code and maybe someone can help.

Comment: @lan MacDonald  Ok, I like to hear about why it's not a good idea,  and I will show some code later, thanks.